# I have a Laravel error and I can't find anything in this code

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7

I'm using Laravel 5.7 and I am getting errors in this code.

**CustomersController.php**

```
<?php

use App\Customers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CustomersController extends Controller
{
   public function list() 
   {
      $customers = Customer::all();
      return view('internals.costumers.blade.php',[
          'customers' => $customers
      ]);
   }
}
```

**internals.costumers.blade.php**

```
@extends('layout')

   @section('content')
      <h1>This is Customers</h1>
      <ul>
         @foreach ($customers as $customer)
           <li>{{ $customer->name }}</li>
         @endforeach
     </ul>
   @endsection
```

Comment: What is the error message you're getting?

Comment: You should tell what error you are getting and try remove .blade.php from the view name ```view('internals.costumers.blade.php',[
        'customers' => $customers,
    ]);```

Comment: Is `internals.costumers.blade.php` mispelled? I wonder if it should be `internals.customers.blade.php`?

Answer (score 0):

Please define namespace  in controller and in view helper pass only name of blade file with parameters instead of with extension:  `.blade.php`